# How to get desired output in row RDLC report

Tags: reporting, rdlc

I have the following report below i can get all the rows

```
SERVER NAME COUNT1   COUNT2     Count+% 7days  count+% 30days
All Servers
( Server1,
 Server2,
Server 3)   7   1,501     500 (20%)     850 (53.3%)

Server 1    2   705       200 (28.3%)   350 (49.6%)

Server 2    3   396       100 (25.2%)   200 (50.5%)

Server 3    2   400       200 (50%)         300 (75%)
```

I have done the last three rows, but how to get the top row? How can we sum up all the rows.In the top row as above?

the others are simple countDistint and count ,

For Count+ % students :

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged7Days.Value = "no", 1, 0)) &" ( "& FormatNumber((Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged7Days.Value = "no", 1, 0)) *100) / count(Fields!f_IdPupil.Value),2) & "%) "
```

And simply change column to 30days , for the next one basically they tell if the student was present in 7 days, 30 days time.

SAMPLE DATA:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just add a group or table header row to the table?

Comment: @IanPreston the issue is the rows are an expression so i cannot just take the sum of it...

Comment: You should just be able to apply the same expression in the header row. Can you update your question with some sample data and the expression(s) you're using so we can replicate exactly what you're seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your expression in any table/group header row; it will just be applied in that current scope, e.g. in a group header the aggregate will be applied to all rows in the group, and in a table header it will be applied to all rows in the dataset.

Say I have the following data:

[image]

I've created a simple report based on this:

[image]

You can see there are two table header rows, one with headings and one with data, and one group header row - the group is based on `ServerName`.

For the **7 Day Expression** column both the fields in the table header row and the group header row have exactly the same expression:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged7Days.Value = "no", 1, 0))
    & " ( "
    & FormatNumber((Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged7Days.Value = "no", 1, 0)) * 100)
  / count(Fields!f_IdPupil.Value),2) & "%) "
```

The is just your exact same expression with some minor formatting. A similar expression is applied in the **30 Day Expression** column:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "no", 1, 0))
    & " ( "
    & FormatNumber((Sum(IIf(Fields!Logged30Days.Value = "no", 1, 0)) * 100)
  / count(Fields!f_IdPupil.Value),2) & "%) "
```

You can see the results are as expected at both the group and grand total levels:

[image]

All this is to show that you just need to apply the same expression in the different scopes to get your results. If this doesn't look right to you; please let me know what results you expect based on my dataset.

Comment: sorry was away will test above and let you know , thank you for taking time to do this.

Comment: This is nearly perfect , only one thing in the 2nd header row instead of all servers i want the server names like (server1,server2,server3 ,,,,any in the list is that possible?)